# How can I know which flags are available for GCC to link library more easily?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-flags

While reading documentation on some library, I saw that some library have some feature, like compiling program using those library more easier, with just typing '`-something`' in the GCC argument instead of typing the path to library or using pkg (`... -- cflag --clibs`).

How can I get the list of those '`-something`' for libraries or packages currently installed on my system?

For example, OpenGL flags:
`-lGLUT -lGL`

They are surely stored in a GCC's config file when I use the package manager to install new library, or how GCC would know how to use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those libraries are *not* stored in any configuration file.

If you check the [GCC link options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) you will see an option "-l" which is used to select libraries to link with. What that option does is to look for libraries in a specified path.

If you look in the folder `/usr/lib` you will see a lot of files named like `/usr/lib/libgtkspell.so.0.0.0`. This if for a library named gtkspell. You link with it by using `-lgtkspell`, the linker will automatically add the other parts when searching for the file.

The `pkg-config` application is good for libraries that need special extra GCC flags, either when compiling (`--cflags`) or linking (`--libs`). But the actual flags `pkg-config` adds to the compilation/linking are just standard GCC flags.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know those flag, since i didn't know what argument to gave to pkg.
But i found out how it was working:

In /usr/lib/pkgconfig there is everything we need. Only put one of those file in argument, + --cflag and --clib.

(i didnt know i was suppose to look at /usr/lib/pkgconfig)